# How - where to backup an app database as restore it on iPhone

Tags: iphone, database

What do you do for app database backup?

On other phones that have SD Cards backup of the app database is not a problem as I can make the backup of the app database to the SD Card. I can also send that backup to email as a zip. Restoring is also not a problem as the email can save the zip to the SD Card use a file that i still on the SD Card.

iPhone seems to be another story.  I can make a copy of the user part of the database and store it in the same documents folder that the app resides.  I could also email a zip of that file in case the phone dies.

but how would I save a download from an email attachment to the app document folder? so if the user uploaded their DB to their email, and then wants to restore it, how would you do this?

What do you all do for DB backups from your apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save the document from an email you could do the following:

First, modify your Info.plist file to register to handle the specific extension of your backup file by adding it to a new key called CFBundleDocumentTypes.

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>MyApplication</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.myapplication.myapplicationsuffix.fileextension</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

The next thing to set up is your application's bundle URL Types.

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.myapplication.myapplicationsuffix.myoperationkey</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>packageforlaunch</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

That way when the user launches the file (taps on it in the email), it will launch your application and provide a filesystem URI to it.  In your app delegate, you can implement the -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url method.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
     if(url != nil && [url isFileURL])
    {
        NSData *d = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[url lastPathComponent]] contents:d attributes:nil];
}
```

That will give you the file and you can save it to your application.  The key here is to not have your database stored in the application bundle, but instead in your application's user folder somewhere.  That way you can easily replace it ( as long as you have the proper locking in place ) from an application launch.  With CoreData, you have to be careful that you have not changed the schema, or that you are loading the correct .xcdatamodeld files for the database version, or you could end up with an un-openable database.

What I have done is to use the SQLite data store for CoreData, or to use SQLite by itself.  Lock the file briefly, create a copy of the database file and upload it via PUT / POST to my server via an API.  The server then stores the file in CouchDB with the timestamp.  This has the effect of being a poor man's versioning system, you could always roll back since the database is tagged with either the user's id, or the user's UDID, or both with the timestamp.

The simpler method will likely be to use a combination of Apple's new document store for the database, and the key/value store with a pointer to the document id that represents the backup.

Unfortunately, I don't think there is an easy mechanism for this, the email mechanism you describe is probably the simplest, but with CoreData, it makes even that complicated.  If you are using raw SQLite3 and the FMDB library, it makes things much easier.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the details!  I really appreciate your time in doing this!!! Currently the app has a zip file in the bundle which I unzip when the app is installed, to the app documents folder. That becomes the DB for the app to use. Should I be putting it somewhere else?  It seems to let me write other files to the docs folder without any problem.   I also have created a backup of the database in the same docs folder.  Should I be putting that somewhere else too?

Comment: Also on the info.plist... is this part of XCode or the OS?  I assume I change the com.myapplication.myapplicationsuffix.fileextension to be my app? is there anything else I need to change?

Comment: The info.plist file is typically one you have to create, it specifies metadata about how iOS should interact with your app.

Comment: I usually put things pertaining to the operation of my app in the user's library folder since Apple doesn't expose the user's library folder when you enable iTunes file sharing as it does the documents folder.  But they are functionally the same.

Comment: What is the myoperationkey?   and also what do I put in for packageforlaunch is that the app name with app on the end or ?

Comment: the myoperationkey is the simple string handed to your application from a launch.  For what you are doing it isn't strictly necessary.  It was intended to have one application launch another application and pass it a piece of data like a user id so the next application could load that user's data from a remote api.

Comment: I have been trying to make the email attached file opeen my app for the last month.  I have put it on the back burner hoping I would figure it out, but tried again for the last couple of days.  I made a post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324422/file-attached-to-email-i-am-trying-to-open-myapp,  could you possibly tell me what I did wrong?